# VSCode extensions doesn't work since today

Tags: visual-studio-code

I currently have a problem with VSCode. 
All of my extensions doesn't work anymore since today.
I have already try to uninstall et install the extensions
Same thing with VSCode

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/octAw.png)

Someone could help me ?

Comment: please check whether you have windows update performed in these 2 days.

Comment: Hello Ken, i'm on mac